# NSMenuItem not being enabled?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, nsmenuitem

I have an NSMenuItem called history which resides in a NSMenu called menu. When my program starts history doesn't have a submenu so its disabled. Then at some point, I need a submenu for history, so I create it, make it a submenu of history. An arrow appears beside history which tells me that the submenu is there. But history is still disabled. I have tried setEnabled but doesn't work. Please help. Here my code:

This is when I create my menu, and history as you can see an NSMenuItem in menu.

```
    menu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu"];
[[menu addItemWithTitle:@"History" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""] setTarget:self];
[[menu addItemWithTitle:@"Settings" action:@selector(loadSettings:) keyEquivalent:@""] setTarget:self];
[[menu addItemWithTitle:@"Quit" action:@selector(terminateApp:) keyEquivalent:@""] setTarget:self];
```

At this point, history is disabled (greyed out).
Then somewhere in the program I need to have a submenu for history so:

```
        if (historyMenu == nil) {
        historyMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Lyrics history"];
        [menu setSubmenu:historyMenu forItem:[menu itemWithTitle:@"History"]];
    }
```

I now see an arrow beside history, but it's still greyed out.

Please help, I have been trying to figure this out for last 2 hours. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You are setting the target but have a nil action. Try not setting the target. This may leave it enabled all the time in which case you may have to manually enable or disable the menu item.

[Here is the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html) on how menu items get enabled.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I don't to set an action method? In fact, I don't even need to set a target, I don't know why I have it there. Anyways, I will try what you said, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

I had to override the `validateMenuItem` method to `return true`:

```
override func validateMenuItem(menuItem: NSMenuItem) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

It didn't actually use the validation method until I set target to self though like you did with

```
menu.addItemWithTitle("An Item", action: #selector(itemPressed), keyEquivalent: "")?.target = self
```

Answer (score 0):

macOS will handle the `enabled` state automatically based on it is being handled or not. So if you are setting an `action` you also need to set the target of the action.

```
let menu = NSMenu()
let itemPress = menu.addItem(withTitle: "some name..", action: #selector(press), keyEquivalent: "")
itemPress.target = self
```

and taget:

```
@objc func press() {
    print("pressed...")
}
```